Libreswan IKEv2 VPN connection successful, client IP not updated
I'm setting up an IKEv2 VPN using Libreswan 3.25, and I'm encountering an issue where I can successfully connect to the VPN, but my laptop's IP address is not being updated to reflect the VPN connection.
Here's my current connection configuration in /etc/ipsec.d/test.conf:
conn test
  left=%defaultroute
  leftsubnet=172.31.30.94/32
  leftid=18.217.218.254
  right=%any
  rightaddresspool=192.168.0.1-192.168.0.254
  modecfgdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
  authby=secret
  ikev2=insist
  ike=aes256-sha2_256-modp2048,aes256-sha1-modp1024
  esp=aes256-sha2_256,aes256-sha1
  modecfgpull=yes
  leftxauthserver=yes
  rightxauthclient=yes
  leftmodecfgserver=yes
  rightmodecfgclient=yes
  xauthby=file
  dpddelay=30
  dpdtimeout=120
  dpdaction=clear
  auto=add
  rekey=no
  fragmentation=yes
  forceencaps=yes

When I connect to this VPN:

The connection appears to establish successfully.
However, my laptop's IP address does not change.
I'm unable to access resources that should be available through the VPN.
I am able to ping 172.31.30.94 successfully

I've tried changing leftsubnet to 0.0.0.0/0, but this resulted in a total loss of internet connectivity.
What am I missing in my configuration to ensure that:

All my client's traffic is routed via the VPN?

I do not want to upgrade my libreswan version, due to other VPN connection running
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
